# How to control overlapping of gallery images?

Tags: android

I am downloading images from a URL and putting them into a gallery.

When the images are downloaded they are loaded correctly.

Once they are loaded from cache, the images are overlapping each other.
How can i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `android:spacing` attribute of the Gallery view.

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter getView() set the imageView background to some color. It will automatically set the next gallery item with that background. But bcoz image is loaded after that your problem will be solved.
Let me know if this doesnt work.

Comment: background color Or background ?

Comment: if you have just a color as default background(like white or blue) set it to background attribute.

Comment: However, I don't recommend using gallery in the first place. It has been deprecated for very long time.