# Prevent Gallery images from overlapping without using setSpacing

Tags: android, gallery, spacing, onkeydown

Is there a way to prevent gallery images from overlapping without using setSpacing?

My gallery uses auto rotation made with `g.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);` which is apparently is the best way to accurately scroll it programmatically, but unfortunately setting spacing prevents onKeyDown from working, for some reason.

Or maybe there is a way to remove spacing (not setting to 0)? Idea is to remove it right before scroll and set back after scroll.

Would be glad to hear any advices.

Comment: I also have this problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to remove image overlapping in a gallery, then there is already a solution.
[How to controll overlapping of gallery images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984694/how-to-controll-overlapping-of-gallery-images/10874633)